# Help translating this sentence: "They're speaking a different language"

Tags: mandarin, sentence-structure

I've run this through Google translate, and received this: 他们说的是不同的语言

**Pinyin:** Tāmen shuō de shì bùtóng de yǔyán

I would have expected it to be something like: 他们说不同的语言

**Pinyin:** Tāmen shuō bu tóng de yǔyán

So my version, I guess it would equate to "They speak different language"

- Should I include 在 (zài) before the verb to indicate "speaking" vs "speak"?
- Why in the first example does the 的 particle exist twice and what role does **shì** play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to express a present continuous tense, yes, a "在" is necessary, cause "他们说不同的语言" express a fact. They may be not speaking now.
2. The 他们说的是不同的语言 is not the exact translation. A better version for "They're speaking a different language" should be: 他们在说不同的语言，as yours. On the other hand, a better English translation of "他们说的是不同的语言" should be: They *were* speaking a different language, or "What they were speaking is a different language". The second one is a bit strange, but can help you to understand the twice "的" and "是"。他们说的 ："What they were speaking"， 是 ：is， 不同的语言： different language.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, 多谢! One other questions is in regard to the use of 正在 and 在 when speaking in continuous tense. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: @Adrift Literally, the meaning of 正在 and 在 are 99% same (when express the continuous tense) and interchangeable. The only very small difference between them (in my opinion) is, compared with 在，正在 emphasized the current state more. For example, if A said : i had something needed to talk to B, you could say 他正在睡觉呢！to emphasize B's state (shouldn't be disturbed). But anyway, you can also use "在" here.